# py2neo to BOLT: how to convert tx.append statements to BOLT

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

In Py2neo there is the ability to append transactions and then commit them as one block to the server

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph()
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
stmt1 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Guinevere'})"
stmt2 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Tom'})"
stmt3 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Anna'})"
tx.append(stmt)
tx.append(stmt2)
tx.append(stmt3)
tx.commit()
```

I can't seem to find the equivalent syntax in  the BOLT Neo4j-driver manual to get it to work. Append is not recognized.

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost",
                                     auth=basic_auth('neo4j', 'password'),
                                     encrypted=True,
                                     trust=TRUST_ON_FIRST_USE)
session = driver.session()    
tx = session.begin_transaction()
tx.append(stmt1) --this does not work
tx.append(stmt2) --this does not work
tx.append(stmt3) --this does not work
tx.commit() --this does not work
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I've tryed as you seeing below and it worked:

`from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase`

`driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost")`

`session = driver.session()`

`stmt1 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Guinevere'})"`

`stmt2 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Tom'})"`

`stmt3 = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Anna'})"`

`tx = session.begin_transaction()`

`tx.run(stmt1)  # returned <neo4j.v1.session.StatementResult object at 0x7f3838f77a58>`

`tx.run(stmt2)  # returned <neo4j.v1.session.StatementResult object at 0x7f3838f77a58>`

`tx.run(stmt3)  # returned <neo4j.v1.session.StatementResult object at 0x7f3838f77e10>`

`tx.commit()  # worked   ;)`

ref:
https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/#example

Answer (score 0):

JRenato's answer was indeed correct. I was confused by the word run and append. I believe they have slightly different meanings.

I had also simplified my example. My problem arose from trying to use the same connection for another set of appended statement. It seems that you need to close the session to avoid issues - otherwise python may complain that the session is still open for a new begin_transaction()